# Libgdx || Box2D Body frustum Culling?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, light, box2dlights

Im currently developing a little dunguen crawler and because i only got about 200 fps on desktop i really need to fix my code :).
My game uses a algorithm for creating different levels with different rooms and so on. Because rooms got walls, i loop trough them and create bodys.
On a 50x50 map there plenty of bodies now and all are calculated and rendered on the same time :(. I also use Box2d Lights and the rayhandler for creating shadows, every body casts shadows :)

Is there a way to implement frustum culling ? And if yes how :) Any code samples?
Are there any other ways to improve the fps rate on bodys ?

Thank you for your time and attention :)

Comment: well i don't think the slow down is because of the bodies, because I was able to run one of my project at 60fps with more than 3000 bodies. The slow down could be caused by your rendering??? Also, you mentioned that that you are "calculating and rendering" at the same time? What does that mean? please show some code or clarify.

Comment: What i didnt mentioned is, that i use also box2d lights and rayhandler, the bodies also casts light :)

Comment: 200 fps? Even 60 should be enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old. But it appears to be the first hit concerning frustum culling with box2d and / or libgdx. And as I created a tutorial to that I wish to post it here, may future people in need can use it

http://erqdev.com/2017/02/26/frustum-culling-with-box2d/

Comment: Your Tutorial Is great ! Thanks for that :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm doing some stuff in the future especially for libGDX and box2D. Would be glad, if you come back!
(magnet effect, radar..)

Comment: This link is dead and archive.org didn't capture it. Is there a mirror somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to get the content online back again, but I can't pay for the domain anymore, and WordPress isn't helping me now. At least here is the code for frustum culling https://github.com/keeyzar/LibgdxFrustumCulling

Answer (score 0):

I think the largest impact on performance in your setting is box2dlights (but to be sure you should do some profiling). Box2dLights in fact has a culling logic which is not perfect but does some basic stuff. To improve the performance of box2dlights you could:

- Reduce the number of rays
- Make the RayHandler FBO smaller
- Set some lights to X-Ray (won't cast shadows)
- Reduce the number of objects (e.g. merge small wall pieces or something)